# X-axis values VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code to create a chart.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim aChart As Chart
    Dim aRange As range


    Set aRange = range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(6, 4))
    Set aChart = Charts.Add
    aChart.HasLegend = False
    aChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    aChart.SetSourceData aRange
    aChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
    aChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
    aChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, Sheet1.Name
    Sheet1.ChartObjects.Left = 125
    Sheet1.ChartObjects.Top = 250
    Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

The values that appear on the X-axis is 1,2,3,4,5. However, I would like to have my values from the worksheet. Do anyone now the code I need to use to get a set of values from a range in my sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim aChart As Chart
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim axisRange As Range

    Set aRange = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(6, 4))

    ' set the x-axis range
    Set axisRange = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(6, 3)) '<-- modify this range according to your needs

    Set aChart = Charts.Add
    aChart.HasLegend = False
    aChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    aChart.SetSourceData aRange
    aChart.PlotBy = xlColumns

    ' set the x-axis chart to your created address
    aChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & axisRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

    aChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
    aChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, Sheet1.Name
    Sheet1.ChartObjects.Left = 125
    Sheet1.ChartObjects.Top = 250
    Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: When I add the code, I get an error '438'; object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: aChart.SeriesCollection.XValues="=" & axisRange.Address (False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

Comment: @Gjovis  did you also add the line Dim axisRange as Range ?

Comment: Yes I did add it

Comment: @Gjovis strange, when I run this code it works for me, maybe you can add a screen-shot of your chart's data, what should go to values and what for x-axis ?

Comment: I made it work, sorry for late replay. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
"='Sheet1'!$A$1:$D$1"
```

etcetera